# How to logical compare two data frames in R

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(QuantTools)

date_from <- '2018-11-01'
date_to <- '2018-11-30'
ticker <- 'SPFB.RTS'

# get days
dataDaily <- get_finam_data(ticker, date_from, date_to, 'day')
# get hours
dataHourly <- get_finam_data(ticker, date_from, date_to, 'hour')

# percent change of the day
dataDaily$pc <- ((dataDaily$close - dataDaily$open)/dataDaily$open)*100

# mark days with > 2 percent change
dataDaily$isBigCh <- dataDaily$pc[dataDaily$pc > 2]
```

So, I have a code above which downloads a daily/hourly OHLC data of the futures.

Questions:
1) How can I move the marks from `dataDaily$isBigCh` to `dataHourly`? It seems not easy because these data frames have different time formats and different lengths of rows.

```
dataHourly$time # has a format like this 2018-11-09 23:00:00
dataDaily$date # has a format like this 2018-11-09
```

2) How can I select the first bar of the day in `dataHourly$time`?

Comment: I guess something like `dataHourly$date <- as.Date(dataHourly$time)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified code for readability

```
# percent change of the day
dataDaily[, price_change := ( close / open - 1 ) * 100 ]

# mark days with > 2 percent change
dataDaily[, isBigCh := price_change > 2 ]
```

Question 1

```
# add date column to hourly data
# note that 00:00 time corresponds to 23:00-00:00 candle
dataHourly[, date := as.Date( time - as.difftime( '01:00:00' ) ) ]

# copy dataDaily isBigCh to dataHourly isBigChDaily
dataHourly[ dataDaily, isBigChDaily := isBigCh, on = 'date' ]
```

Question 2

```
# select first bar of the day
dataHourly[, .SD[1], by = date ]
```

Optionally

```
# remove date column from hourly data
dataHourly[, date := NULL ]
```

Note

- `library(data.table)` not necessary as `QuantTools` loads it automatically
- please read `data.table` manual it will save you lots of time trying to figure out simple manipulations similar to what you asked